# When renting a server can I set the minimum players to 4 for all game modes?

Tags: battlefield-3

When playing on the Xbox 360, I noticed that most of the online game modes have no active servers.  I have tried joining specific game modes with friends but we have found that the servers don't start until at least 8 people join (you are stuck in a warm-up round until enough join).

There is a rent-a-server option that allows us to create our own server, and we can control certain settings.  One is to reduce the minimum players, which I believe is 4.  This would be enough for us to get games going on game modes without an active community.  Between the 5 of us we can at least start a game before others join.

Before one of us pays anything to rent a server, does anyone know if we can set **ALL** game modes to a minimum of 4 players, on ranked games.  We want to get games going and then hopefully draw in other players.  We are looking at such games modes as gun master and scavenger game modes (as well as all the others).  I don't know if different game modes have different requirements.

Just a note, team deathmatch, conquest and rush are still heavily populated.

Comment: I didn't tag this question with a platform because answers for PS3 and the PC are also welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Xbox 360 I was able to set the minimum number of players to 4.  This worked for every game mode.